# Unable to install 'gensim' on Python 3.8.0

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, gensim, pipenv, python-3.8

Getting the error below when I try to install `gensim` on `Python 3.8.0`. How can I make it work, is there any workaround?

Here is the full error stacktrace:

```
The following command was executed:

C:\Users\talha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pipenv.exe update --dev

The exit code: 1
The error output of the command:

Running $ pipenv lock then $ pipenv sync.
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (ec3971)…
Installing initially failed dependencies…

Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…

[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[   =] Locking...
[  ==] Locking...
[ ===] Locking...
[====] Locking...
[=== ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[    ] Locking...
[=   ] Locking...
[==  ] Locking...Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (ec3971)!
An error occurred while installing scipy==1.3.1 --hash=sha256:0baa64bf42592032f6f6445a07144e355ca876b177f47ad8d0612901c9375bef --hash=sha256:243b04730d7223d2b844bda9500310eecc9eda0cba9ceaf0cde1839f8287dfa8 --hash=sha256:2643cfb46d97b7797d1dbdb6f3c23fe3402904e3c90e6facfe6a9b98d808c1b5 --hash=sha256:396eb4cdad421f846a1498299474f0a3752921229388f91f60dc3eda55a00488 --hash=sha256:3ae3692616975d3c10aca6d574d6b4ff95568768d4525f76222fb60f142075b9 --hash=sha256:435d19f80b4dcf67dc090cc04fde2c5c8a70b3372e64f6a9c58c5b806abfa5a8 --hash=sha256:46a5e55850cfe02332998b3aef481d33f1efee1960fe6cfee0202c7dd6fc21ab --hash=sha256:75b513c462e58eeca82b22fc00f0d1875a37b12913eee9d979233349fce5c8b2 --hash=sha256:7ccfa44a08226825126c4ef0027aa46a38c928a10f0a8a8483c80dd9f9a0ad44 --hash=sha256:89dd6a6d329e3f693d1204d5562dd63af0fd7a17854ced17f9cbc37d5b853c8d --hash=sha256:a81da2fe32f4eab8b60d56ad43e44d93d392da228a77e229e59b51508a00299c --hash=sha256:a9d606d11eb2eec7ef893eb825017fbb6eef1e1d0b98a5b7fc11446ebeb2b9b1 --hash=sha256:ac37eb652248e2d7cbbfd89619dce5ecfd27d657e714ed049d82f19b162e8d45 --hash=sha256:cbc0611699e420774e945f6a4e2830f7ca2b3ee3483fca1aa659100049487dd5 --hash=sha256:d02d813ec9958ed63b390ded463163685af6025cb2e9a226ec2c477df90c6957 --hash=sha256:dd3b52e00f93fd1c86f2d78243dfb0d02743c94dd1d34ffea10055438e63b99d! Will try again.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\talha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2604, in do_sync
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       do_init(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\talha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1246, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       do_install_dependencies(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\talha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 858, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       batch_install(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\talha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "c:\users\talha\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting scipy==1.3.1', '  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/5b/5afcd1c46f97b3c2ac3489dbc95d6ca28eacf8e3634e51f495da68d97f0f/scipy-1.3.1.tar.gz', '  Installing build dependencies: started', '  Installing build dependencies: still running...', "  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'", '  Getting requirements to build wheel: started', "  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'", '    Preparing wheel metadata: started', "    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'"]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:', "     command: 'd:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\scripts\\python.exe' 'd:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\pep517\\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp88ndh32u'", '         cwd: C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ppv6gock\\scipy', '    Complete output (172 lines):', '    lapack_opt_info:', '    lapack_mkl_info:', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', "      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['d:\\\\.virtualenvs\\\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\\\lib', 'C:\\\\']", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    openblas_lapack_info:', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', "      libraries openblas not found in ['d:\\\\.virtualenvs\\\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\\\lib', 'C:\\\\']", "    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'", '    customize GnuFCompiler', '    Could not locate executable g77', '    Could not locate executable f77', '    customize IntelVisualFCompiler', '    Could not locate executable ifort', '    Could not locate executable ifl', '    customize AbsoftFCompiler', '    Could not locate executable f90', '    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler', '    Could not locate executable DF', '    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler', '    Could not locate executable efl', '    customize Gnu95FCompiler', '    Could not locate executable gfortran', '    Could not locate executable f95', '    customize G95FCompiler', '    Could not locate executable g95', '    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler', '    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler', '    Could not locate executable efort', '    Could not locate executable efc', '    customize PGroupFlangCompiler', '    Could not locate executable flang', "    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    openblas_clapack_info:', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', "      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['d:\\\\.virtualenvs\\\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\\\lib', 'C:\\\\']", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    atlas_3_10_threads_info:', '    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\\', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\\', "    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    atlas_3_10_info:', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries satlas,satlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\\', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\\', "    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    atlas_threads_info:', '    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\\', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\\', "    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    atlas_info:', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\\', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', '      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\\', "    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    lapack_info:', "    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils", '    customize MSVCCompiler', "      libraries lapack not found in ['d:\\\\.virtualenvs\\\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\\\lib', 'C:\\\\']", '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    lapack_src_info:', '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '      NOT AVAILABLE', '    ', '    C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\ma\\core.py:4462: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?', '      if self.shape is ():', "    setup.py:386: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-modern-metadata-kh8x6t2r'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates", '      warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command (\'{}\'), proceeding with "', '    C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\distutils\\misc_util.py:464: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?', "      return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)", '    Running from scipy source directory.', '    C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\distutils\\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:', '        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.', '        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the', '        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting', '        the ATLAS environment variable.', '      self.calc_info()', '    C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\distutils\\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:', '        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.', '        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the', '        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting', '        the LAPACK environment variable.', '      self.calc_info()', '    C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\distutils\\system_info.py:624: UserWarning:', '        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.', '        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the', '        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting', '        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.', '      self.calc_info()', '    Traceback (most recent call last):', '      File "d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\pep517\\_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>', '        main()', '      File "d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\pep517\\_in_process.py", line 240, in main', "        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])", '      File "d:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\pep517\\_in_process.py", line 110, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel', '        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)', '      File "C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\build_meta.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel', '        self.run_setup()', '      File "C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\build_meta.py", line 236, in run_setup', '        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,', '      File "C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\setuptools\\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup', "        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())", '      File "setup.py", line 505, in <module>', '        setup_package()', '      File "setup.py", line 501, in setup_package', '        setup(**metadata)', '      File "C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-1qw9t5p7\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\distutils\\core.py", line 135, in setup', '        config = configuration()', '      File "setup.py", line 403, in configuration', '        raise NotFoundError(msg)', '    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.', '    ----------------------------------------', "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\scripts\\python.exe' 'd:\\.virtualenvs\\pyemoji-fylffy3g\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\pep517\\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\\Users\\talha\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp88ndh32u' Check the logs for full command output."]
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...

Error Running Pipenv
```

p.s. Using `pipenv` as the packaging tool.

Comment: `No lapack/blas resources found`. http://www.netlib.org/lapack/ & `Atlas libraries not found` http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This appears to involve `scipy`, specifically, rather than `gensim`. (Neither the command reported as run, `pipenv.exe update --dev`, nor any of the error output mentions `gensim`.) So, have you tried specifically uninstalling & reinstalling `scipy`, and watching for any specific errors when trying that?

Comment: Nothing was changed; getting `An error occurred while installing .! Will try again.` @gojomo

Comment: I faced the same issue while using conda to install the gensim package. The conda package is not always up to date which results in this kind of conflict. I used pip installer which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Scipy wheels on pypi (1.3.1 and below)  are not compatible with python 3.8. Wait for scipy 1.3.2, which should be released soon

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I'd like to learn if there are any places that I can check which packages have a compatible release with Python 3.8 rather than individually checking respective PyPI documentation?